# Eclipse PHP code formatter removes pipe symbols from @return comments

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc, formatter

I'm using Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1) for a PHP project.

I've stumbled across a problem with the eclipse code formatter for PHP regarding PHPDoc's @return with pipe (vertical bar) symbol:
When having a comment like this:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @param string|array The parameter. Either a string or an array.
 * @return int|string The return value. Either an int or a string.
 */
function test($param) {
}
```

Using the format function with [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[F] results in:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @param
 *          string|array The parameter. Either a string or an array.
 * @return int string return value. Either an int or a string.
 */
function test($param) {
}
```

As one can see, the pipe symbol between 'int' and 'string' in the '@return' statement has been replaced by a space. But not only that. Also the first word of the description ('The') has been chopped off. On the other hand, it works just fine for the '@param' statement.

phpdoc.org states, that the pipe symbol is used when handling ambigous return values: [phpdoc-@return](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/return.html)

Somebody also asked a question about this int the Eclipse Community Forums: [Forum Post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/683282/) just a few days ago.

Using '@formatter:off' and '@formatter:on' is no option, since this setting is only local and others might not have it set.

Does anyone know how to fix-configure the eclipse php code formatter? Does anybody have a workaround?

Comment: as far as I know, there's a @return mixed for these kind of situations, anyhow, I would suggest you to use more "php friendly" IDE like PhpStorm.

Comment: The problem with 'mixed' as return type is, that it could be anything. Using the pipe symbol I can say that it is either type A or type B. That again is helpful with autocomplete in eclipse. Using an other IDE is no option either, because it is a company guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Thats been reported as a bug -- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431979